# Can a taunt have crits/mini-crits?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Some taunts can deal damage (like the Gunslinger, Frontier Justice etc.)

But can they have special damage, like crits or mini-crits?

Comment: Would it matter? They all one hit kill anyway.

Comment: @Studoku Several taunts do damage in several stages.  For instance, the Spy's Fencing taunt hits twice for damage, only the third hit is instant kill.  Likewise, the Gunslinger hits several times for damage before the final instant kill.

Comment: @Studoku Also, the Dead Ringer blocks 90% of incoming damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the wiki pages of [critical hits](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Critical_hits), There is one statement that link the two mecanisms.

> If the player is under a **Mini-crit buff state** (such as the Buff Banner or Buffalo Steak Sandvich), or the victim is under a Mini-crit debuff state (such being Jarated or marked for death), **all taunt attacks will also Mini-crit.**

Is the same thing applies for full crits ?
Well, if we look at the definition of a [crit boost](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Critical_hits#Crit_boost) :

> Crit boost is a state in which a player is guaranteed to deal critical hits with **any weapon**

Given the fact that a special icon is attached to taunt kills (i.e. [image: PAW - haha !]) I assume that the use of a weapon has been required to make the kill. So, this makes the taunt attack critical while the player is under the crit boost.

Comment: Given that a taunt attack does 400 or 500 damage, it is an instant kill almost every time when it hits.

Comment: "Given the fact that a special icon is attached to taunt kills (i.e. PAW - haha !) I assume that the use of a weapon has been required to make the kill" As far as I'm aware, taunt kills don't have an associated weapon.  Instead, they have a custom kill type set, which controls the kill icon shown.

Comment: I believe It would be easier to implement these methods in the code with the plain addition of unselectable, invisible weapons, which are only linked with the taunting animations.

Comment: I admit I haven't had a chance to check, but chances are they just use the World (entity 0) as the weapon.  This is what they do for things like fall damage... they just assign the attacker as the last person to deal damage.

Comment: Incidentally, in TF2, the method for damage done to a player passes the victim, attacker, inflictor (the projectile entity for projectiles, otherwise the weapon or world), damage, damagetype bitfield, weapon, a damage force vector, a damage position vector, and a damagecustom enum value.  For the Heavy's first taunt, that enum value would be `TF_CUSTOM_TAUNT_HIGH_NOON` (value 9).